# FFMEG one input multiple resolution outputs for streaming and recording

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

An input rtmp stream I need to encode in multiple resolutions with different audio bitrates. Each of these outputs is streamed and recorded too. tee muxer doesn't seem to be working. I am trying

```
ffmpeg -i input rtmp://server
-map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 720k -f tee "[f=flv]record720.flv|[f=flv]rtmp://streamingserver/720"
-map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:1 540k -f tee "[f=flv]record540.flv|[f=flv]rtmp://streamingserver/540"
-map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:2 360k -f tee "[f=flv]record360.flv|[f=flv]rtmp://streamingserver/360"
-map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:3 240k -f tee "[f=flv]record240.flv|[f=flv]rtmp://streamingserver/240"
```

Am getting errors about tee muxer.

Comment: What errors exactly? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Share full log.